# Keyboard stops working randomly

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11

For last few days my keyboard stops working randomly. I tried restarting the computer, updating the driver and altering the power settings. Also keys are not working in boot options of Windows. In the BIOS and secure mod, they works fine. Mouse working as well everywhere.

While I tried pressing all the keys, I realized only brightness, plane mode, and touchpad key work (also fn key). Sometimes all the keys work, and then they suddenly go.

I'm using Lenovo Legion 15ARH05 laptop. My Windows 11 is 64 bit.

---

**Edit:** I can enter the BIOS by the F2 key, but the keys not working after this in BIOS. The microphone, fn, fnlock, brightness, airplane, and touchpad buttons are still working. The other keys are completely gone including the capslock key's light.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckwxx.jpg]

[image]

Comment: Failing ribbon cable, or swollen battery. Check yourself or send for service.

Comment: But if there is any hardware situation, it should not work in the BIOS too either. Isn't it?

Comment: Try an external USB keyboard. If that works, it confirms keyboard hardware issue, as @Tetsujin suggests. Replacement keyboards are advertised for US$24 and up, it's *not* another issue, such as swollen battery.

Comment: Ok, i'll check it. Thanks :)

Comment: I checked the ribbon cable twice, but it looks like fine. There is no damage or any other problem in case including the battery. I will update the post with images.