# Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05 the RAM lid causes the black screen

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, ramdisk

Since 15 September, I had a keyboard problem on my Lenovo Legion 5 15ARH05 laptop. I opened a [question](https://superuser.com/q/1807755/167207) to solve it, but had to send the laptop to the customer service at last. Then the motherboard has changed and the laptop came back.

First day it worked perfectly, but today I had an another problem. When I try to turn on my laptop, the lights came on but the screen didn't. I tried to do AC Reset, restart, etc. But it didn't work.

Then I opened the back lid of the laptop and tried many things. I plugged out the battery, HDD, SSD, CMOS battery and plugged in but it didn't work again. I thought it could happen due to RAM, so I lifted off the RAM lid and tried to plug out the top RAM then plug in.

It worked, but when I tried to plug the lid in, didn't work again.

So, the RAM lid was causing the problem. But why? I checked for the short circuits due to the lid, I didn't find anything. Now, my laptop is working without the lid but don't know the reason that causes to black screen. Why might this problem happen?

[image: The RAM Lid 1]

[image: The RAM Lid 2]

Comment: Bring the laptop again to the customer service - it's most likely their problem.

Comment: You're right, but I'm too tired to send it back. As I said, I had this problem since the 15 September. I sent it a third time and they delayed me for weeks every time. It's so annoying to wait until the shipping arrives to them, and then wait for it back. I hope this problem happens only because of a lid.

Comment: Does the battery looks as if it has swollen ?

Comment: @John I think so, but the black screen occurs when I put it back.

Comment: @harrymc No, it's normal.

Comment: As @John states, could be that a layer of clear insulation is missing. To reduce RF noise and chance of damage to RAM, I'd put some *thin* cellophane tape on any spot on the lid, inside or outside, that might touch metal and replace the lid. Also, does the lid press down on RAM? If so it could poorly seated -- remove it and carefully replace.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks. I'll try to put tape on the lid, and replace it. It may press down, but I didn't consider it. Next time I'll check.